# A read only balance tracker

Tags: wallet, altcoin, tracking

Is there an app where I could add my public keys for several alt-coins that I have, to see the current balances. Kind of like a multi-currency wallet/tracker, but read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this site https://cointracking.info which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Does it work given *only* wallet public addresses? Because I don't want to keep my money in an exchange.

Answer (score 0):

several approaches, just wondering about the public keys, that you mention... wouldn't you have "amounts", that should be multiplied by current value (in Euro or Dollars) per currency? Then this:

http://www.coindetail.com/

alternativly the el-cheapo version at the command line, which I cut&paste into an ods (xls) or similiar:

```
#!/bin/sh
####################################################################
### an 'el cheapo' approach to fetch data from coinmarketcap.com ###
####################################################################

log_fn=ccy_values.log

echo "`date '+%Y-%B-%d'`"                       > $log_fn
echo "`date '+%H:%M'`"                         >> $log_fn
echo "running ccy_values.sh on `hostname -s`"  >> $log_fn
echo " " >> $log_fn

today="`date '+%y%m%d%H%M'`"

wget -q -O - https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=EUR   > /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp
wget -q -O - https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=EUR >> /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp
wget -q -O - https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/aeon/?convert=EUR     >> /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp
wget -q -O - https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/siacoin/?convert=EUR  >> /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp
wget -q -O - https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/storj/?convert=EUR    >> /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp
wget -q -O - https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/storjcoin-x/?convert=EUR    >> /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp
cat /Data/tmp/tmp_$today.tmp | grep -e "id" -e "price_btc" -e "price_eur" | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,/ /g' > $log_fn

# create terminal output 
tail -n 18 $log_fn | awk 'BEGIN { print "Currency (source: coinmarketcap.com)\tConversion Rate (Bitcoin)\tin EUR"} { ORS=""; print $2; if( NR % 3 == 0) print "\n"; else print "\t";}'
```

Comment: I understand that I could use an API. My question was whether there is a ready app for that, so that I could always check the balances and their USD value from my phone.

Comment: I see. The weblink does that (and a bit more), I am not aware of an app. I use this to see the status of my coins on my mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread from Google, but noticed there were no good answers.

[**MoonRekt.com**](https://moonrekt.com/) - This is a Portfolio Tracker Service that also has the ability to **add Bitcoin public addresses to "watch."** You can also add trades from exchanges as well.

Hope this helps anyone looking for a Bitcoin Read Only Wallet. More coins will be supported soon.